# What is the context of the verse 4:34 of Quran?

Tags: quranic-events

What is the context of the verse 4:34 of Quran?

> Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth. So righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's] absence what Allah would have them guard. But those [wives] from whom you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist], forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you [once more], seek no means against them. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted and Grand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commentary of the said verse  by Al Wahidi explains the occasion of its revelation:

> Said Muqatil: “This verse (Men are in charge of women…) was revealed
>   about Sa‘d ibn al-Rabi‘, who was one of the leaders of the Helpers
>   (nuqaba’), and his wife Habibah bint Zayd ibn Abi Zuhayr, both of whom
>   from the Helpers. It happened Sa‘d hit his wife on the face because
>   she rebelled against him. Then her father went with her to see the
>   Prophet, Allah bless him and give him peace. He said to him: ‘I gave
>   him my daughter in marriage and he slapped her’. The Prophet, Allah
>   bless him and give him peace, said:
>
> ‘Let her have retaliation against her husband’.
>
> As she was leaving with her father to execute retaliation, the
>   Prophet, Allah bless him and give him peace, called them and said:
>   ‘Come back; Gabriel has come to me’, and Allah, exalted is He,
>   revealed this verse. The Messenger of Allah, Allah bless him and give
>   him peace, said: ‘We wanted something while Allah wanted something
>   else, and that which Allah wants is good’.
>
> In another narration, Yunus ibn al-Hasan who reported that a man
>   slapped his wife and she complained about him to the Prophet, Allah
>   bless him and give him peace. Her family who went with her said, “O
>   Messenger of Allah! So-and-so has slapped our girl”. The Prophet,
>   Allah bless him and give him peace, kept saying,
>
> “Retaliation! Retaliation! And there is no other judgement to be
>   held”.
>
> But then this verse (Men are in charge of women…) was revealed and the
>   Prophet, Allah bless him and give him peace, said: “We wanted
>   something and Allah wanted something else”.
>
> http://quranx.com/Tafsirs/4.34

It seems that the Prophet made a mistake in his judgement and Allah corrected him by sending his angel.